# At least 45W power output at most 300g power bank?

Tags: power-bank

This used to exist, the [Lenovo USB-C Laptop Power Bank](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories/acc500091-lenovo-usb-c-laptop-power-bank-14000mah-g0a3140cxx-overview-and-service-parts) was 290g but it's discontinued. The [Omni Mobile 12800](https://eu.omnicharge.co/products/omni-mobile-12800) was 270g but it's discontinued as well.

What alternatives are available end of 2023?

The Nitecore NB20000 is 324.5g, I wonder whether we could do better.

Comment: By 45W, do you mean 45W of maximum power output or 45Wh of capacity?

Comment: 45W power output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zendure SuperMini X3 10000mAh](https://powerbank.zendure.com/products/supermini-x3-10000mah-portable-power-bank)

> 45W Power delivery output, […] weighs only 200g

And this one is actually available right now although the US is crossed out and only CA shows availability -- Canada I guess.

There's the [Elecjet Apollo Pro](https://www.mobicares.com/en/elecjet/apollo-pro-graphene-usb-c-pd-power-bank-9000mah-hong-kong-only) and while I can't find the exact weight it stands to reason this 9000mAh power bank can't be much more than 200g either. Alas, it seems to be a Hong Kong exclusive. The Elecjet Apollo Ultra has received widespread praise (or perhaps it's just puff pieces? hard to say but there are some positive posts on reddit too) but it seems it's no longer available either.

Another would be the Excitrus Power Bank Air but is also gone so much so the myexcitrus.com page is now a parked domain. (I have an Excitrus 65W charger and it's great, verified by a teardown review.)

4Smarts has a [Power Bank Pocket Slim 10000mAh 45W](https://b2b.4smarts.eu/Power-Bank-Pocket-Slim-10000mAh-45W-white) and I see a a few French sellers on eBay. As a bonus it even supports through charging although this [image](https://b2b.4smarts.eu/media/image/product/5676/lg/540654%7E9.jpg) suggests it only charges at 27W while discharging at 45W. The page doesn't have the weight, amazon.com claims 6.7oz or 190g.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these

- [Excitrus Portable Laptop Charger,45w Power Bank Air USB C Ultra Small Light](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PJHPDN2)

  45W, 7.05oz (199.9g)

[image]

- [Excitrus 83W Power Bank Pro, USB C Real Ultra Slim Portable Charger High Speed, Power Delivery Power Bank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B093G7WTP3)

  83W, 10.41oz (295g)

[image]

Comment: I saw. Much as the other two I listed it's unavailable. So is the Elecjet Apollo Ultra. But I _do_ have a solution I just found, let me post it.